# Send multiline String via HTTP Post in Java

Tags: java, http, post, multiline

I want to send post request to some service using Java. Requests must contain some parameters and one of them is multiline String. I tried many ways but everytime I end up with whole text submitted as single line without newline characters. Any ideas?

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/create");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
String data = "param1=value&string=" + convertNewLineCharacters(text);
writer.write(data);
writer.flush();

// (...)
private String convertNewLineCharacters(String text) throws Exception  {
  String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
  encodedString = encodedString.replaceAll("%0A", "\r\n");

  return encodedString;
}
```

I am limited to standard Java Api, so no external libraries are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ); // not sure it is important
// ...
writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8")); // urlencode the whole string and do not edit it
// ...
```

Comment: Maybe the error is on the other side, on the app receiving the form. Would you show us that code?

Comment: This is not my web application so source code isn't available :) url: [link](http://pastie.org/pastes/new). I even tried post a request with Firefox plugin but I still get single line.

Comment: ok, looks like I made a mistake and your suggestion is working. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.foo;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Foobar {
    public static void main(String...args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String text = URLEncoder.encode("Foo\nBar", "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(text, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Output:
Foo
Bar

Just decode the encoded data. `URLEncoder#encode(String s, "UTF-8")` will percent encode any characters outside of the reserved set. See [Percent encoding of character data.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data)

Comment: Yeah, but I am afraid that is not the case. All I need is the way how to send multiline String with POST so that web application receiving this will see it as multiline text posted in textarea.

Comment: The "web application" receiving this POST **must** decode it before using it. Set the correct content type as shown by @user270349.